# Where can replacement parts be acquired for adams vibraphones?

Tags: maintenance, percussion, vibraphone

I have an Adams Endurance Field Frame for a vibraphone and the high capacity spring that allows the pedal to function has broken due to wear of the medal. I have been searching around but cannot find a site that sells replacement parts for these frames, and more importantly, the spring. I was curious on where these parts are sold or what a good alternative would be for the spring. I have tried another spring not made by Adams but it was not powerful enough and does not allow the pedal to come all the way back up.

The spring works by pulling the pedal back up rather then pushing the mute bar into the keys so it needs to be that type of spring.

Comment: Just a tip: I would try a local locksmith.

Comment: Can you contact Adams?  https://adams-music.com

Comment: Do you have the original, now broken, spring? Take it to an engineering supplies store. Don't worry too much about the attachment points, they can be modified. Go for the right spring characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a retailer of Adams parts here: [American Music Sales](http://www.americanmusicsales.com/shop/brand2.asp?storeID=921C847E287B4417B9618051B22BC67B&menu=&seg=0&subtype=&subtypeid=0&alpha=&brand=Adams&brand_id=1083). There are a number of springs listed there (I did a simple CTRL + F). They have parts such as "Cord and Springs for 4.0 Oct. Xylophone". I don't see a cord and spring set for a vibraphone on there, but they may be fairly universal parts?

Ultimately it might be best to contact Adams and get a part number from them. I've had good luck with Yamaho who, following a phone call with their distributor for my country, emailed me a parts inventory for the instrument I needed a part for. I was then able to purchase directly from Yamaha, though Adams might not have the same policy. I'm old fashioned and like picking up the phone. Apparently they can be phoned on +31(0) 475 560710 [as per their website here.](https://www.adams-music.com/contactinfo/)

Things may only get murky if Adams is not the OEM, in which case you are chasing down a generic part.